# Is there an alternative to get_template_directory_uri()?

Tags: functions, themes, actions

I need to know the templates directory uri at a point at which the function `get_template_directory_uri()` is not yet available.

The function where I need the uri is triggered by the action `after_switch_theme`.

So is there any other way to achieve this? Or can I make is somehow available?

Answer (score 0):

It is a sign that you are "doing it wrong". you should not assume the existance or initialization of anything before the `init` action was fired, or even better to wait for `wp_loaded`

Comment: I tried the same thing with `wp_load` instead of `after_switch_theme` as this would still work in my case, but `get_template_directory_uri()` is still unknown.

Comment: well, maybe it is time to actually put your code in the question so we all will be able to see what we are talking about ;)

Answer (score 0):

[`after_switch_theme`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_switch_theme/) passes the old theme's name and an instance of [`WP_Theme`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_theme/) class. So, you should be able to use that to construct a path for your theme's URI.

Here's an example:

```
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'my_function', 10, 2 );
function my_function( $old_theme_name, $old_theme = false ){
    if( $old_theme ){
        $uri = $old_theme->get_template_directory_uri();
    }
}
```

This is only valid if the old theme still exists.